# Show that each equivalence class has the same cardinality as N.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, equivalence-relations

Define a relation $R$ on $\mathbb{N}$ by declaring that $x R y$ if and only if $x = y\alpha^2$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$. Show that each equivalence class has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N}$.

Not really sure how to proceed working through this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well can you just start by noting that two sets have the same cardinality if and only if there exists a bijective function between the two sets? So for a certain equivalence class can you construct a one to one correspondence between the elements of the equivalence class to the elements of $\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that since the cardinality of equivalence classes is equal, it is enough to prove that the class containing $1$ has cardinality equal to that of $\mathbb{N}$. Now, $\forall\ x \in$ the equivalence class of $1$, then $\exists\ a \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x = a^{2}$.

$$\implies |\mathbb{R}_1| = |\{a^{2}: a \in\ \mathbb{Q}\}|$$
$$\implies |\mathbb{R}_1| = |\mathbb{Q}| = |\mathbb{N}|$$

Hence, proved.

Here's my approach for the relation on $\mathbb{N}$.

**Claim**: $\forall\ n \in \mathbb{N}, a \in \mathbb{Q}\ \land a^2 = n \implies a \in \mathbb{N}$

Proof: Let $\exists\ n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a \in \mathbb{Q}\ \land a \notin \mathbb{N}\ \land a^2 = n$

$\implies \exists\ p, q \in \mathbb{N}$ such that gcd($p, q$) = 1 & $n = \frac{p^2}{q^2} \implies n \notin \mathbb{N} \implies \impliedby$

$$\implies |\mathbb{N}_1| = |\{a^2: a\in \mathbb{N}\}| = |\mathbb{N}|$$

Hence,  proved.

Comment: Oh I thought the relation was on $\mathbb{R}$ not $\mathbb{N}$. Still leaving my answer up until I think of the right answer, so that the approach is public.

Comment: Why must the cardinality of equivalence classes be equal?

Answer (score 0):

The number theory part of this is that two natural numbers are in the same squareclass if and only if their product is a square.

The set theory part is that any set of natural numbers has a minimum, call it $m$ for some class of interest. Furthermore, $m$ is squarefree. The class is the set of all $m n^2$ for $n = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...$